# Mathematica Style Solution to String Parsing

Tags: string, parsing, styles, wolfram-mathematica, cycle

I want to take a string of the form "(ABC)(DEF)" and translate adjacent pairs of letters into numbers, interpreting the letters inside parenthesis as cycles.  From my example I would want to generate the table:

{{"AB", 1}, {"BC", 2}, {"CA", 3}, {"DE", 4}, {"EF", 5}, {"FD", 6}}

I could do this with a loop, but my limited knowledge of the 'Mathematica  Style' of coding suggests that there is a better way to do this in Mathematica.  How do I do this the Mathematica way?  In general where can I learn about Mathematica style coding?

Edit: Changed my mind.  I want to create a function, f, such that f["AB"] = 1, etc. but I don't think this will change the problem much.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to return `1` given the input "ab":

```
f["ab"] = 1
```

Where can you learn about the Mathematica way of programming ?  From the documentation, from many reference books, [on the Mathematica stack exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?as=1), from Leonid Shifrin's [advanced introduction to Mathematica programming](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org), lots and lots of other places too.  But the best place is at your keyboard with your fingers and mind fully engaged.

Comment: Mark, it's been a while that I wanted to ask: why don't you join us at Mathematica stack exchange? Your expertise will be much appreciated there.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I don't go along with the ghettoisation of Mathematica programming.  I'm a programmer not a <insert name of language> programmer.  My Fortran programming is better for being a Mathematica programmer too, and my Mathematica programming is better for being a Fortran programmer too.  Taken to the extreme we'd have a Stack Exchange site for each programming language, we'd all be losers, especially the newbies who think that their only language is the one true language and who have so much to learn from exposure to other ways of thinking.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that. I am a programmer too (Java, C, Javascript, Mathematica), and I can say the same about different programming skills enhancing each other. Indeed, on Mathematica Stack Exchange programming problems are only a (relatively small) fraction of all questions. However, even that fraction still provides more of the interesting purely programming questions currently than Mathematica tag here, because most of the Mathematica tag SO community moved there (otherwise I would not have left - I am still the top user in this tag :)).